# Redirect folders with rewrite rule

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a set of URLs like these:

- http://www.immvestwolf.de/unternehmen-2-2/uebersicht/jeden-tag-besser/
- http://www.immvestwolf.de/unternehmen-2-2/team-old/architekten/
- http://www.immvestwolf.de/unternehmen-2-2/uebersicht/ein-team-das-verbindet/

Now I want to redirect all urls with `/unternehmen-2-2` in the url to the page `http://www.immvestwolf.de/unternehmen/`

I tried several solutions but none worked for example:

```bash
RewriteRule unternehmen-2-2/(.*) /unternehmen/ [L,R=301]
```

or

```bash
RewriteRule ^unternehmen-2-2 /unternehmen/ [L,R=301,NC]
```

Anybody an idea?

Here is my htaccess:

```bash
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/[0-9]+$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [QSA,L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^expose/(.*)$ content/index.php?content=expose&query=$1 [L,QSA]

#RewriteRule unternehmen-2-2/(.*) unternehmen/ [L,R=301]

#RewriteRule ^unternehmen/darstellung/(.*)$ content/index.php?
content=unternehmen/darstellung&query=$1 [L,QSA]
#RewriteRule ^unternehmen/team/(.*)$ content/index.php?   

content=unternehmen/team&query=$1 [L,QSA]
#RewriteRule ^unternehmen/referenzen/(.*)$ content/index.php?  
content=unternehmen/referenzen&query=$1 [L,QSA]
#RewriteRule ^unternehmen/partner/(.*)$ content/index.php?  
content=unternehmen/partner&query=$1 [L,QSA]
#RewriteRule ^unternehmen/karriere/(.*)$ content/index.php?  
content=unternehmen/karriere&query=$1 [L,QSA]
#RewriteRule ^unternehmen/verbundpartner/(.*)$ content/index.php? 
content=unternehmen/verbundpartner&query=$1 [L,QSA]
#RewriteRule ^unternehmen/$ content/index.php?content=unternehmen&query=$1  
[L,QSA]
#RewriteRule ^unternehmen/(.*)$ content/index.php?  
content=unternehmen&query=$1 [L,QSA]

#RewriteRule ^hausverwaltung/(.*)$ content/index.php?  
content=hausverwaltung&query=$1 [L,QSA]
#RewriteRule ^investment/(.*)$ content/index.php?content=investment&query=$1  
[L,QSA]
#RewriteRule ^kontakt/(.*)$ content/index.php?content=kontakt&query=$1 
[L,QSA]
#RewriteRule ^kontakt2/(.*)$ content/index.php?content=kontakt2&query=$1 
[L,QSA]
#RewriteRule ^vermietung/angebote/(.*)$ content/index.php?  
content=vermietung/angebote&query=$1 [L,QSA]
#RewriteRule ^eigentum/angebote/(.*)$ content/index.php? 
content=eigentum/angebote&query=$1 [L,QSA]

#RewriteRule ^service/vermietung/(.*)$ content/index.php? 
content=service/vermietung&query=$1 [L,QSA]
#RewriteRule ^service/eigentum/(.*)$ content/index.php? 
content=service/eigentum&query=$1 [L,QSA]
#RewriteRule ^service/$ content/index.php?content=service&query=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code:-

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^unternehmen-2-2/?$ /unternehmen [L,R=301,NC]
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Although this won't "redirect all urls with `/unternehmen-2-2` in the url" - it will only redirect match that exact URL. But then if this works, then your second example should also have worked - which perhaps suggests a caching issue?

Comment: @w3dk oh i see you are right. this rule won`t redirect all URLs with `/unternehmen-2-2` in the Url. Is there a rule which redirects all URLs with `/unternehmen-2-2` in it???

Comment: Try this rule:- Redirect 301 /unternehmen-2-2 /unternehmen ***OR*** RewriteRule ^(.*)unternehmen-2-2(.*)$ $1unternehmen$2 [R=301,L]

Comment: Well, in theory, you'd only need to remove the trailing `/?$` on the `RewriteRule` _pattern_. However, this is then "the same" as the second example stated in the question (except for the trailing slash on the _substitution_), which then begs the question (as per my comment)... why didn't it work the first time? (Btw, you should never mix `Redirect` (mod_alias) and `RewriteRule` (mod_rewrite) redirects since they belong to different modules they run at different times so you can easily end up with a conflict.)

Comment: thanks for your answer! When i make `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^unternehmen-2-2 /unternehmen [L,R=301,NC]` (in seperate lines) i get a 500 error...